# Is there a way to plot separate functions in 3D using Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

Is there a way to plot separate functions in 3D using Wolfram Alpha? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Similar problem with GeoGebra
[image]

Comment: WolframAlpha can be a bit touchy.  I would recommend either [CalcPlot3D](https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/) or [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d?lang=en) for plotting in 3D online.

Comment: Yeah, I tried Geogebra and it doesn't work either. Wait a sec pls, I will show you my screen from GeoGebra.

Comment: This works for me https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x+%2B+3y+%2Bz+%3C%3D+6

Comment: Yeah but you plot just 1 function. The problem is, I need to plot multiple functions (and in Geogebra I can't plot even one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot multiple functions in GeoGebra. It looks like it doesn't handle inequalities well in 3D; try writing them as strict equalities.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it works, Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alternative via [CalcPlot3D](https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/?type=implicit;equation=2x+3y+z%7E5;cubes=16;visible=true;fixdomain=false;xmin=-6;xmax=6;ymin=-6;ymax=6;zmin=-6;zmax=6;alpha=173;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=implicit;equation=x%5E2+y%5E2+z%5E2%7E5;cubes=16;visible=true;fixdomain=false;xmin=-6;xmax=6;ymin=-6;ymax=6;zmin=-6;zmax=6;alpha=-1;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=z;z=(x%5E2*y%5E2)/(x%5E2+y%5E2+1);visible=true;umin=-6;umax=6;vmin=-6;vmax=6;grid=30;format=normal;alpha=-1;constcol=rgb(255,0,0);view=0;contourcolor=red;fixdomain=false&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=29.183676174951387,3.0673279666094038,6.237350724532782,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=-0.3073241669467797,-0.03230107154560232,0.9510565162951534,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=true;showaxes=true;showticks=true;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.49841017488076317;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=false;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-6;xmax=6;ymin=-6;ymax=6;zmin=-6;zmax=6;xscale=1;yscale=1;zscale=1;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;zoom=0.252444;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=1):

[image]